# Isosceles or Right Triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Do the points $A(6,4)$, $B(4,-3)$, and $C(-2,3)$ form an isosceles triangle or a right triangle? How do you know?

I tried converting these to polar coordinates..

Comment: How about computing the side-lengths of the triangle?

Comment: Why polar?  Compute the distances between all the points.

Comment: I highly recommend graphing those points and then computing the distances between them.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compute $$AB=\sqrt{(4-6)^2+(-3-4)^2}=…$$
$$BC=\sqrt{(-2-4)^2+(3-(-3))^2}=…$$

Answer (score 2):

$$AB=\sqrt{(4-6)^2+(-3-4)^2}=\sqrt{53}\\BC=\sqrt{(-2-4)^2+(3-(-3))^2}=\sqrt{72}\\AC=\sqrt{(-2-6)^2+(3-4)^2}=\sqrt{65}$$This is not a right triangle because $a^2+b^2\ne c^2$.

This not an isosceles triangle because no two sides are equal.